# Making Android app hidden numbers visible... which are for pro app only

Tags: android

I have one app, which not allowing me to see certain numbers. Those numbers are blurred. I can see that those numbers are keeps on updating behind that blurred part. How can I make those numbers visible?

Comment: Are you developing this app?

Comment: Are you trying to trick the developer of that app? If seeing these numbers is only available in a paid version of that app, you should either pay for it or not see them

Answer (score 0):

Is this an app you made or someone else?

It sounds like you are trying to make numbers which are blurred in another developers app visible which you cannot do.

If this is within an app you have made then please provide sample code of how the numbers are shown, updated and blurred and information as to where these numbers are so I can take a look.